# Directus | Validation for related field are not working

Tags: directus, directus-flows

When we configure the validation for child data model from parent data model using validation tab and then its not working in latest version ( 9.21.2), but it was working in old version like 9.10.0

- I have created two entity such as Parent and Child.
- I have related the Parent and child using Many to many relationship.
- Parent Entity   with Many to many relationship with child:

[image]

Child Entity:

[image]

In parent, we child field (many to many field), and then there is a validation tab in which i have configure the validation for field in child, but its not working.

[image]

In following screenshot, you can see that i'm able to create child with empty title

[image]

[image]

Note: I dont want to configure the validation in Child data modal because i planned to create multiple relationship field with same Child data modal, so each time, i will use different validation rules, so Parent is the better place to configure it.